I am trying to preprocess the image before passing it to the pytesseract. Image is of the Nutrition facts of the product
I have this image. and I want the extracted character of only the nutrition components from this.
I don't know the which types of the preprocessing step will help. I need the extracted character only and there might be the case of on applying the only one type of the preprocessing step in the real time system.
